# Sorting array using medians

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, median

So lets Assume that you have an algorithm for a method that finds the median of an array and lets call this method X. X would basically find the median of an array a ( a is unsorted) in O(n) time. How would i be able to design an O(n log n)-time algorithm to sort array a, using X as a helper method.
Cant really fathom the fact that the median will help me sort the array … ??

Thanks

Comment: Here you go big guy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by applying X recursively. Consider the following sub-routine Y:

1. Given an array of length `n` as input, we first apply the method X to find the median `m` of the input numbers, this takes time `O(n)`.
2. We then scan the input array to rearrange the numbers in the array so that all the numbers smaller than `m` are on the left hand side of the array, whereas all the numbers larger than `m` are on the right hand side of the array (and `m` is in the middle of the array), note that this step also takes time `O(n)`.

Hence on input array of length `n`, the sub-routine Y takes `O(n)` time in total.

So if you recursively apply the sub-routine Y to the sub-arrays to the left and right of the median `m` and continue the process, the output will be a sorted array and the total time is given by:

```
T(n) = O(n) + 2 * O(n/2) + 4 * O(n/4) + ... + 2^log(n) * O(n / 2^log(n)) 
     = O(n) + O(n) + O(n) + ... + O(n)     // log(n) terms in total
     = O(n log(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Quick sort, the worst case complexity to sort the array is O(n^2) if the pivot is chosen randomly.

But there are variants of quick sort, whose worst case time complexity is O(nlgn). In these variants pivot element is the median(n/2th element) of the array or pivot position is a function of array size, so that it can divide the array into two parts which are function of array size(not constant).